# How do I find the final rule?

Tags: united-states, regulations

My question concerns the Healthy, Hunger-Free Kids Act of 2010.  Provisions of this act were to be phased in, in stages.  I wanted to figure out where things stand currently, i.e. what exactly is required as of now, so I looked at the relevant USDA press releases at the USDA [Food and Nutrition Service website](http://www.fns.usda.gov/school-meals/press).

There I found a press release about a Final Rule that I am interested in understanding better: [Local School Wellness Policy](http://www.fns.usda.gov/school-meals/fr-072916c).

There was a proposed change to the rule.  I find it all very confusing.  I'm just trying to find what is actually currently in effect (full text).

Perhaps someone with experience looking up laws will have an easier time finding the full, current text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this document](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2016/07/29/2016-17230/local-school-wellness-policy-implementation-under-the-healthy-hunger-free-kids-act-of-2010), you should search for the text (at the bottom) that reads:

> Accordingly, for the reasons set forth in the preamble, 7 CFR parts
>   210 and 220 are amended as follows

This states what the changes are. The resulting consolidated regulations (sections of interest) are [here](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=ca93f37bd752da8c045c5984dcac4ed1&mc=true&node=pt7.4.210&rgn=div5#se7.4.210_130) and [here](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=ca93f37bd752da8c045c5984dcac4ed1&mc=true&node=pt7.4.220&rgn=div5). As you will see, the changes are spread out all over the place, so to really understand the current state of the regulations, you need to read parts 210 and 220.

Comment: Thank you -- but isn't there a document somewhere which incorporates the old and the new, to give me the actual text in one place?

Comment: Eventually, the changes made via the Federal Register will be incorporated in to Code of Federal Regulations, 7 CFR parts 210 and 220. But, there is a lag between publication in the federal register and actual inclusion of the amendments to the regulation in an accessible version of the CFR. Lawyers in regulation heavy areas of practice and like to use paper normally buy an updated printed version every year or two.

Comment: Actually, the ECFR version is current, and has those changes.

Comment: Sorry, I see now.  You've given me exactly what I requested.  Thank you!  Now I'm wondering how you found these things, that I was having so much trouble finding.  Should I ask another question, about how one goes about finding "consolidated regulations"?  (I love that phrase.)

Comment: Mostly Google-fu. I looked in the USDA news article you mentioned, found a link to the federal register, went to the bottom (that's why they call it the bottom line), got the revisions and section citations. I use ECFR because it's the better portal and you can search larger swathes of regulations. I did a bit of manual verification to compare the Fed Reg announcement and what ECFR says, though ECFR gives you the "current as of" data at the top. The Cornell version isn't up to date.